# How Postgres avoid "iteration invalidation" and you can loop over rows and modify the data at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, invalidation

I wonder how PG manages to allow the change in the table while you iterate it at the same time.

In special, I looking for how this is done at the low-level/internals of the engine, because *I wish to replicate the idea*.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value   TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id, value) values (1, 'a');

DO
$function$
DECLARE
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Can add while iterating?
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'ADD ROW..:%', row;
        INSERT INTO test (id, value) values (2, 'b');
    END LOOP;
    -- Yes, and the new row is not visible in the loop

    -- Can update while iterating?
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'UP ROW..:%', row;
        UPDATE test SET value = 'c' WHERE id = row.id;
    END LOOP;
    -- Yes, and the updated rows do not affect the iteration and you see the old value

    -- Can update and see the new row?
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'UP ROW..:%', row;
        UPDATE test SET value = 'd' WHERE id = row.id;
        
        SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = row.id AND value ='d' INTO row;
        IF row IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'FOUND ROW..:%', row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    -- Yes, we can see the change if run another query
    
    --Can remove while iterating?
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'DEL ROW..:%', row;
        DELETE FROM test;
    END LOOP;
    --Yes, and the deleted rows do not affect the iteration
END
$function$;
```

It looks to me that `PG` is loading all the rows then iterating on memory, similar to this Rust code:

```rust
// instead of:
fn main() {
    let mut table = vec![1, 2];
    
    for row in table {
        table.push(3);
        dbg!(row);
    }

    // is doing
    let query = table.clone();
    for row in query {
        table.push(3);
        dbg!(row);
    }    
}
```

However, that must be very inefficient. In special, I found interesting is how this is possible:

```sql
   -- Can update and see the new row?
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM test
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'UP ROW..:%', row;
        UPDATE test SET value = 'd' WHERE id = row.id;
        
        SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = row.id AND value ='d' INTO row;
        IF row IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'FOUND ROW..:%', row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    -- Yes, we can see the change if run another query
```

Because this point to the idea PG is having 2 different `cursors`(?) that see different section of the transaction changes.

So, I imagine PG is doing something like this:

| tx_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (1,a) |
| 2 | (1,b) |

And in the loop it get something like `SELECT * FROM data where tx_id <=1` but when you run the next query it gets `SELECT * FROM data where tx_id <=2`?

Comment: Postgres implements [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) as its basic underlying design. Basically it means it keeps multiple versions of the data and everything runs within the scope of a transaction. During the transaction you can see the effects of DML statements within that transaction. But no other transaction can see those effects until you commit (or your app auto commits), nor can you see the DML effects from other transactions.